# Python Increment Ranges

Tags: python-3.x

Looking to create a bar chart that shows the count of rows that fit within a time range (in 15 min increments).

This is what I have so far:

```
hist = []
hist.append((("00:00:00" <= df["Time"]) & (df["Time"] < "00:15:00")).sum())
hist.append((("00:15:00" <= df["Time"]) & (df["Time"] < "00:30:00")).sum())
hist.append((("00:30:00" <= df["Time"]) & (df["Time"] < "00:45:00")).sum())
...
hist.append((("23:45:00" <= df["Time"]) & (df["Time"] < "24:00:00")).sum())
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Read about `df.resample(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

This should at least be a less verbose implementation of the same logic, using a loop to count up time and f-strings to put it into a string to be compared with the dataframes.

```
hist = []
hour = 0
minute = 0
while hour < 24:
    nextminute = minute + 15
    nexthour = hour
    if nextminute >= 60:
        nexthour += 1
        nextminute -= 60
    hist.append(((f"{hour:02}:{minute:02}:00" <= df["Time"]) 
               & (df["Time"] < f"{nexthour:02}:{nextminute:02}:00")).sum())
    hour = nexthour
    minute = nextminute
```